# Reload data in table nightly - Query against table times out first time it is run, and subsequent queries are fast?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing, timeout

I have a table with the following primary key:

```
WeekEndingFriday
Employee
Project
Phase
Task
```

It also has an index on WeekEndingFriday,Employee.

The table has 2,025,597 records in it.

Every night I delete and reload the last 2 weeks of data...it's approximately 6,500 records.

I have some stored procedures that populate data in a dashboard...after the nightly reload of the last 2 weeks of data, the first time the stored procedure is run that uses that table, it times out (takes forever and then fails with a timeout). Every execution after that finishes in under 3 seconds.

Why is this happening? How can I make sure that the first execution of that SP is just as fast as the subsequent executions?

Comment: Not on topic, but you can just as well throw away that index if the primary key is ordered the way you describe, since the index is just a subset of the PK.

Comment: thanks...was just trying anything...

Comment: Is it possible the data is on disk and takes a while to load the first time? Can you just make a quick select that you throw away to see if that speeds stuff up?

Comment: @MattiasÅslund I don't know what is causing it...I added an exec of the SP after the data is reloaded. It worked but that seems cludgy...I was hoping there was something a little more professional like rebuilding statistics or something like that. I don't know why it would behave the way it is.

Comment: Does the problem still exist? How does the SP look like? Is it complex with a lot of `if`s and so on? Becasue then it might be that it is recompiled and that takes long.